# Difference between Arrays.fill() and a for loop for initializing Array of linkedlist

Tags: java, arrays

why this gives different output.

```
LinkedList<Integer> blocked [] = new LinkedList[n+1];
int obstacles [][]= {{5, 5},{4 ,2},{2 ,3}};

CASE 1: Arrays.fill(blocked, new LinkedList<Integer>());
System.out.println(blocked);  

OUTPUT :  
[5, 2, 3]
[5, 2, 3]
[5, 2, 3]
[5, 2, 3]
[5, 2, 3]

CASE 2:  for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
         blocked[i]= new LinkedList<Integer>();
OUTPUT : []
         [3]
         []
         [2]
         [5]
```

why this is working differently , is using new linkedlist in arrays.fill is sending same object reference?

Comment: whats this `LinkedList<Integer> blocked [] = new LinkedList[n+1];` ? does it compile?

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for Arrays.fill() that you are using:

```
public static void fill(Object[] a, Object val) {
    for (int i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++)
        a[i] = val;
}
```

So answer is YES, it using the same instance of Object to fill the array.